# How can I do multiple input streams in logstash?

Tags: logstash

My use case is:

1. I need a timestamp from database A
2. Then do a query on database B
3. Then output the results of that Database B query

Which means a logstash file that (theoretically) would look something like:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    get the timestamp
  }
  jdbc {
    Do the SQL that gets lots of data with the timestamp above
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    spew the data from that second jdbc query
  }
}
```

That doesn't work, of course, but it gives the idea of the use case. How can I make solve this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [jdbc_streaming](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-jdbc_streaming.html) filter, which is designed for exactly this use-case.

Comment: I tried, sadly it can't handle the same query that the jdbc input succeeded on, it blew up the heap.